# Getting web safe fonts working on LinuxMint

Tags: linux-mint, fonts, fontconfig

Is there any way to get all the web safe fonts working on Linux Mint? Right now all these fonts look the same on my OS
[image: Web safe fonts are all the same no matter the fony family]

It'd would be great if someone could point me out a pack of fonts that I can download right away with the replacement font for all these font families.

Comment: There is a package for this: `ttf-mscorefonts`.  If I recall correctly, these are actually downloaded and extracted from a Microsoft website, so you'll want to read the license carefully.  You might also try `fonts-liberation` if it is not currently installed, as that provides truly free variants for some of the common ones.